# First non-null value from a list of dicts using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Let's suppose that I want to get the first value of key that is not null inside this list of objects:

```
const arr = [
    {
      "key": null,
      "anotherkey": 0
    },
    {
      "another": "ignore"
    },
    {
      "bool": True,
      "key": "this!"
    }
  ]
```

Is there some one-liner using Ramda to do this? I made it using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for the first non-null key but answers so far rely on truthyness. In JavaScript a non-null value is not necessarily truthy. Things like `0`, `''` or `false` are all non-null values but they are not truthy.

In my experience it is better to be explicit otherwise you may get unexpected results:

```js
var data = [{key:null, val:1}, {key:0, val:2}, {key:1, val:3}];

find(prop('key'))(data);
//=> {key:1, val:3}

find(propSatisfies(complement(isNil), 'key'))(data);
//=> {key:0, val:2}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Ramda:

```
R.find(R.prop("key"))(arr);
```

`prop` function will return the value of `key` for each element. `find` will return the first `truthy` element from those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first item in the array whose `key` property is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then get the `key` property.

```js
const arr = [{
    "key": null,
    "anotherkey": 0
  },
  {
    "another": "ignore"
  },
  {
    "bool": true,
    "key": "this!"
  }
]


const res = arr.find(e => e.key).key;

console.log(res)
```